# I want to replace same items with multiple values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Here is the code:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'names': ['Fenellas', 'Steve', 'Jo', 'Stephen', 'Lili'],
                   'grade': ['High', 'High', 'Low', 'High', 'Medium']})
```

These two methods are not working.

```py
df = df.replace(to_replace='High', value=['H','Hi'])
```

```py
df = df.replace(to_replace='High', value='H', limit=1)
```

Final output should be:

```
names     grade 
Fenellas  H
Steve     Hi
Jo        Low
Stephen   Hi
Lili      Medium
```

Is there any other good solution?

Comment: How the final output should look like ?

Comment: names grade
0 Fenellas H
1 Steve Hi
2 Jo Low
3 Stephen Hi
4 Lili Medium

Comment: Why *Fenellas*'s High is replaced with *H* and the others with *Hi*?

Comment: If it is a typo, consider this: `df.grade = df.grade.str.replace("High", "Hi")`. Otherwise explain the replacing conditions.

Comment: Suppose, you will fill the missing value, col - vehicle/car. You can give the expensive car to the one whose salary is more. Whose salary is less, you can give inexpensive.

Comment: @Shakib if your last commentary is somehow related to the question and adds more conditions to the problem then you should add this to the code you provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a conditional replacement.

Assuming `'High'` should become `'H'` for the **first** item, `'Hi'` for the rest:

```
df['grade'] = (df['grade']
               .replace('High', 'H') # replace 'High' with 'H'
               # keep this for the first High
               # one could use any other condition, such as name, other col…
               .where(df.groupby('grade').cumcount().eq(0),
               # else replace with 'Hi'
                      df['grade'].replace('High', 'Hi'))
              )
```

output:

```
      names   grade
0  Fenellas       H
1     Steve      Hi
2        Jo     Low
3   Stephen      Hi
4      Lili  Medium
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no explanation on why Fenella's `High` is replaced with `H` while others get a `Hi`.

```
# Find the exact match in `names` and replace with value:

df.loc[df['names'] == 'Fenellas', 'grade'] = 'H'

# Find and replace all `High` values in grades after running the above to change Fenella's grade.

df['grades'] = df.grades.str.replace('High','Hi')
```

Comment: First of all, thank you, brother. 

I first replaced the null values ​​in the Vehicle column with zeros to track the null values.

Now, you have to fill this missing value (zeroes actually), col name - vehicle/car. You can give the expensive car to the one whose salary is more. Whose salary is less, you can give inexpensive car. 

actually that's my desired things.

Answer (score 0):

In case your goal was to assign 'H' strictly to 'Fenellas', and the rest get replaced 'High' to 'Hi'

```py
import numpy as np

df['grade'] = np.where((df.grade == 'High') & (df.names == 'Fenellas'), # condition
                       'H', # value if condition met
                       np.where(df.grade == 'High', # nested condition for the rest
                                'Hi', # value if nested condition met
                                df.grade)) # leave the rest intact
```

In case you wanted to assign 'H' to the first and 'Hi' to the rest, then:

```py
df['grade'] = ['H' if i == 0 else 'Hi' if row.grade == 'High' else row.grade for i, row in df.iterrows()]
```

Answer (score -4):

```
def replacing(x):
  if x=='High':
    return 'H'
  elif x=='Medium':
    return 'M'
  elif x=='Low':
    return 'L'
  else:
    return x

df['grade'] = df['grade'].apply(replacing)
```

You can use the apply method to change values in your df

Comment: This is not the desired output. please read my question again.

Comment: @Shakib well, you also failed to provide a logic, I can find 20 different reasons to give this exact output. You should explain **your expected logic**.

Comment: Suppose, you will fill the missing value, col - vehicle/car. You can give the expensive car to the one whose salary is more. Whose salary is less, you can give inexpensive car. 

actually that's my desired things.